# KivyMD Scrollview Example

Tags: python, android, listview, kivy, scrollview

I was able to find this example of kivymd handling scrollview with MDlist. 
I am struggling to make it run.

The I am not familiar with the error code i am receiving and I was unsuccessful finding any help so far .

Here is the code :

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv =""""
<scrollview>
    ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False  # Important for MD compliance
            MDList:
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "Single-line item"
                TwoLineListItem:
                    text: "Two-line item"
                    secondary_text: "Secondary text here"
                ThreeLineListItem:
                    text: "Three-line item"
                    secondary_text: "This is a multi-line label where you can fit more text than usual"
"""
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root_widget = Builder.load_string(kv)
        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["Paula", "John", "Kate", "Vlad"]
        for c in contacts:
            ml.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(
                    text=c
                )
            )
        return self.root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your `kv` string. First, the opening and ending quotes should match (you start with 4 and end with 3). Second, you have a `<scrollview>` entry. I don't think that is a legal entry. And third, the rest of your `kv` string has inconsistent indentation. It looks like your `kv` string is trying to create a `ScrollView` containing an `MDList`. If that works, then your call to `ScrollView` in the `build()` method will create such a `ScrollView` containing an `MDList`. Then the line `sv.add_widget(ml)` will try to add a second `MDList` to the `ScrollView` (which should produce an error, since only one child is allowed in a `ScrollView`). Then the `build()` method is returning `self.root_widget` which is unrelated to the `sv` that you have just created.

So here is a modified version of your code that uses the `sv` that you create in your `build()` method:

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sv = ScrollView()
        ml = MDList()
        sv.add_widget(ml)
        contacts = ["Paula", "John", "Kate", "Vlad"]
        for c in contacts:
            ml.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(
                    text=c
                )
            )
        return sv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

If you add enough names to the `contacts` list, the scrolling will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. I kept playing in the IDE, I even removed the TwoLineListItem and the ThreeLineListItem. I cant seem to find any KV code that will works. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help. But I've recently got back to working on an App with Kivy and I have a ScrollView with a MDList in it like so:

```
<Manager>:
    Main:
        id: main
        name: 'main'

<Main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: "Email Assistant"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
            elevation: 9
            left_action_items: [["help-circle-outline", lambda x: app.root.get_screen('main').open_dialog()]]
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            columns: 3
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: container

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: container_two
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: 'hello'
            ScrollView:
                Label:
                    id: msg
                    text: 'message'
```

The `<Main>:` is a class in my python file and I use the `MDList id` to input a list of contacts every time it loads up.

Important side note, I do not have my list inside my EmailAssistantApp class:

```
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(Screen):
    def on_kv_post(self, *args):
        for name, email in load_db(database_file).items():
            self.ids.container.add_widget(
                NameList(text=name, icon='account')
            )
    
    def selected(self, n):
        self.ids.name.text = n

class EmailAssistantApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()

        return Manager()
```